# $ dot each not working for recursion (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, foreach

I have a loop in which I am calling rec_append() recursively, apparently the first pass alone works, then the loop stops.

I have an array of 4 elements going into that $.each loop but I see only the first element going into the function recursively. Help!

I switched it for a element.forEach but that gives me only the second element and I am stuck, is there a better solution to process a tree of elements? My array is a part of a tree.

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))
        var graph = $(".entry-point");

        function rec_append(requestData, parentDiv) {

          var temp_parent_details;
          $.each(requestData, function (index, jsonElement) {

            if (typeof jsonElement === 'string') {
              //Element construction

              //Name and other details in the form of a : delimited string
              var splitString = jsonElement.split(':');

              var details = document.createElement("details");
              var summary = document.createElement("summary");
              summary.innerText = splitString[0];
              details.append(summary);
              temp_parent_details = details;
              parentDiv.append(details);

              var kbd = document.createElement("kbd");
              kbd.innerText = splitString[1];
              summary.append(' ');
              summary.append(kbd);

              var div = document.createElement("div");
              div.className = "col";
              details.append(div);

              var dl = document.createElement("dl");
              div.append(dl);

              var dt = document.createElement("dt");
              dt.className = "col-sm-1";
              dt.innerText = "Path";
              div.append(dt);

              var dd = document.createElement("dd");
              dd.className = "col-sm-11";
              dd.innerText = splitString[2];
              div.append(dd);

              var dt2 = document.createElement("dt");
              dt2.className = "col-sm-1";
              dt2.innerText = "Type";
              div.append(dt2);

              var dd2 = document.createElement("dd");
              dd2.className = "col-sm-11";
              dd2.innerText = splitString[1];
              div.append(dd2);
            } else {
              $.each(jsonElement, function (jsonElementArrIndx, jsonChildElement) {
                rec_append(jsonChildElement, temp_parent_details); //Only 1 pass works, rest skip
              });

            }

          });
        }

        rec_append(data, graph);
```

Sample data:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32LTS.png)

Comment: Are you sure `jsonElement` is an array ? you've only got 1 check for a string. also any errors ?

Comment: Yes it is, sometimes it's an Object (key value dict from python), sometimes it's an array

Comment: Can you show a small sample of the known data ?

Comment: Why did you "write" the dot in `$.each()` in the title? o.O

Comment: `temp_parent_details` will be `undefined`, then in your first recursion, you are appending . apend of undefined

Comment: also im not sure `rec_append` i think will return undefined, you will need to return something from a recursive method.

Comment: yes give me a min...

Comment: I've added sample data. Also I don't see undefined anywhere, I debugged my code in chrome

Comment: I'm planning to send linear data from my python file, I think complications in js is a pain, I'm planning to send elements and their paths, so I can figure out a tree structure without having to use foreachs